# The type or namespace name 'Script' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, asp.net, system.web, .net-3.5

I have asp.net website on my local machine including library project. Having issue while building website.
I am using framework 3.5 and visual studio 2010 and my System OS is Windows 10.
Library project having build target platform on any cpu.

I tried with referencing System.Web.Extension.dll from c:/program files/reference assemblies/framework/..
also tried referencing from c:/windows/microsoft.net/framework/..
and also tried with dll from framework64 folder

I can not publish my asp.net web site because it is showing compile time errors.[image]

Comment: Upgrage your project to `Framework 4.6.1`.

Comment: @MuhammadAftab Is their any other solution?

Comment: System.Web.Extension**s** should do it (with 's'). Is your web.config updated too? See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-web-services). If it doesn't work, consider upgrading .net version. it won't hurt anything.

Comment: I got the solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053181/cannot-find-system-web-script-service-namespace-error-after-upgrading-to-visual